# Excel Formula or function that returns the Nth value from a dynamically generated grouping of cells

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to assemble a index/match combination and am having trouble figuring out how to make it work. I have experience with a lot of the formula types in excel, but unfortunately I am pretty ignorant when it comes to these functions.

I will explain what I am trying to do first, but I have attached 3 images at the end that will probably make things more clear.

In order to identify the specific values I want, I am having to use helper cells. These helper cells are denoted with the (helper) tag in the pictures. These cells go through and grab the adjusted closing price of the stock (column A) at the beginning (column C) and the end (Column D) of a dynamically calculated period.

I would like to consolidate these values into numerical order in columns F and G. The thought is that the first non zero number in C/D is belongs to the first predefined period and should go into columns F/G beside the #1 (column E). This gets carried on through all of the periods (ex: 2nd non zero goes beside the number 2, third nonzero number goes beside the number 3 etc.)

This is just an example of one stock. I need the function or formula to be dynamic enough to work on a wide variety of distributions. Sometimes there are up to 100 dynamically calculated periods within the stock analysis.

Below are the images that should provide more clarity

Image 1 is an example of what the data looks like

Image 2 is a crudely drawn example of how I would like the data to move

Image 3 is the desired result

Image 1[image: Example of data]

Image 2
[image: Moving Data]

Image 3
[image: Results]

Updated image for Scott Craner showing out of order results
[image: For Scott Craner]

Please let me know if I can clarify any confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to return the first value of each period (column C) and the last value of each period (column D), you could use index match and lookup to do this without even using helper columns.

Try this in cell F2

```
=INDEX(A2:A50,MATCH(E2,B2:B50,0))
```

And this in cell G2

```
=LOOKUP(E2,B2:B50,A2:A50)
```

Depending on much variance is in your overall number of rows, you could use indirect references in the formulas to dynamically update the ranges. 
Example:

```
=INDEX(A2:INDIRECT("A"&COUNTA(A:A)),MATCH(E2,B2:INDIRECT("B"&COUNTA(A:A)),0))
```

Comment: FWIW, both these formulas are not array type formulas and there is no detriment to using full column references. `=INDEX(A:A,MATCH(E2,B:B,0))`.  The INDIRECT function is volatile and a page full of them may increase calc times on the sheet as it will recalc every time Excel recalcs whether the underlying data has changed or not.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to open macro. Then do the following in recorded macro.
+ Filter only non-null value in C/D
+ Select whole column in C/D then copy the whole column 
+ Turn off Filter
+ Paste the whole C/D in F/G
+ Stop macro

Gook Luck

Answer (score 0):

Put this formula if F2:

```
=INDEX(INDEX(C:C,MATCH($E2,$B:$B,0)):INDEX(C:C,MATCH($E2,$B:$B,0)+COUNTIF($B:$B,$E2)-1),MATCH(1E+99,INDEX(C:C,MATCH($E2,$B:$B,0)):INDEX(C:C,MATCH($E2,$B:$B,0)+COUNTIF($B:$B,$E2)-1)))
```

Copy over one column and down the list.

[image]

Comment: thank you again for taking time to look at my problem. Your formula is mostly working. However, when I put it in to my worksheet, the values are being copied over in the incorrect order. I have edited my post with another image to show you what is happening. As a note, I am in excel 2010 and it looks like you are operating in one of the newer versions. Could this account for the out of order results?

Comment: -sorry forgot to add the handle in my response